# Limit VS Code python list print - vs code prints 1 million elements to the terminal

Tags: python

I have a (hopefully) relatively simple question. I had a python list with 1M+ elements, and I want to limit the elements that VS Code prints to the terminal.

I.e.: I have a python list called "firms_of_interest" that has 1 million firms. When I execute the code "firms_of_interest", VS code prints every single element of the list to the terminal.

How do I get it to only print approximately. 10 elements?

Thank you.

Comment: Do a loop over the list and print as much as you want. Or take a slice of the list and print that. A Python beginner's tutorial may help.

Comment: use a slice: `print(firms[:10])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

1. Simplest way would be to just use slicing:

```py
    $> firms_of_interest[:2]  # print two first firms
    $> ['Apple', 'Google']
```

2. Second simplest way would be to use pandas `Series` class. Class `Series` have very nice implementation of `__repr__` function which by default truncates list in case it is too long.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    firms_of_interest = pd.Series(firms_of_interest)
    $> firms_of_interest
    $> ['Apple', 'Google', ..., 'Microsoft']
```

3. You can try somehow change `__repr__` method of `list` class, though I would not recommend to do it. One of the ways how it could be done:

```py
   class MyList(list):
       def __repr__(self):
           total = f' total elements: {len(self)}'
           return repr(self[:10]) + total  # print first ten elements or less

   $> firms_of_interest = MyList(firms_of_interest)
   $> firms_of_interest
   $> ['Apple', 'Google', 'Microsoft', ...] total elements: 1000000
```

## Explanation of [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) function

In order to know how to display any object in terminal "VSCode" (actually python's shell) calls `repr` function on the object, which returns string representation of the object. Under the hood `repr` function calls a special object's method `__repr__`.

### Examples

```py
    # Class with default __repr__ method
    class Bar:
        pass

    $> bar = Bar()
    $> bar 
    $> <__main__.Bar at 0x7f111cf89e20>  # default implementation of __repr__

    # Class with redefined __repr__ method
    class Foo:
        def __repr__(self):
            return 'I am object of class Foo'
    
    $> foo = Foo()
    $> foo
    $> I am object of class Foo
```

Seems that Python's `list` class implements `__repr__` function in a way that it prints all elements in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the list and not print the whole list

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
x=2
for i in range(x):
  print(thislist[i])
```

[Python - Loop Lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_loop.asp)